# Flutter layout inside a list tile (search bar + dropdown + other widgets)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I implemented a search bar in flutter with the below code and everything is working fine. I am able to get the search bar in the layout. Now, I want to add a dropdown button just below the searchbar.

```
return Scaffold(
body: SafeArea(
     child: ListView (
         children: [
        SearchBar<Post>(
        searchBarPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        headerPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        listPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        onSearch: _getALlPosts,
        searchBarController: _searchBarController,
        hintText: "What do you want to search?",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        cancellationWidget: Text("Cancel"),
        emptyWidget: Text("empty"),
        indexedScaledTileBuilder: (int index) => ScaledTile.count(1, 1),
        onCancelled: () {
          print("Cancelled triggered");
        },
        onItemFound: (Post post, int index) {
          return Center(
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('Item 1'),
                    subtitle: Text('Item subtitle 1.'),
                  ),
                  ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('Find item'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailMedicine()));
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                     color: Colors.amber[600],
                     child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  iconSize: 24,
  elevation: 16,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
       ]
        },

      ),
      
    ),
    
  );
```

I want to put the search bar inside a listview. I tried making a listview and placing the searchbar and other widgets inside the widget list but it is showing blank screen as output. I wonder I am missing something here.

Comment: can you add some sample json data and I cannot see the listview in the code and a dropdown please add the code so that we can check where its going wrong.

Comment: @SagarAcharya: I updated the description. Could you please check now?